# UIButton click by default going to right bar button item click on nav bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UIButton` on `UIView` exactly below the right bar button item.

Most of the time when I tap UIButton, the right bar button item gets clicked.

The height of right bar button item is set properly and does not exceed height of navigation bar.

What needs to be done in this case?

Comment: Move the button further away? The touch screen can only be so accurate and fingers aren't the most precise of pointing tools

Comment: The button needs to be exactly below the right bar button item, as per product design. Any other way to achieve it?

Comment: If it's a usability issues then kick it back to the designers - a finger can only be so accurate.

Comment: Hope this can be done, but not possible. Need technical help now.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I re-read your question. The buttons in navigation bars have a larger hit-area than the navigation bar *by design*. Don't place buttons so close to your navigation bar; they make it difficult for the user to tap one or the other, as you are experiencing.

Make sure that the view containing the button is large enough to contain it completely. If a button is in a view that doesn't clip its subviews, you can *see* the button, but can't interact with it.

```
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
UIButton *button = ...;//whatever button, added target and everything
[containerView addSubview:button];
[contaierView setClipsToBounds:NO]; //NO is the default, anyway
```

In this example, the button would be visible in the `containerView`, but its actions would never be called. Try double checking your views, like this:

```
[containerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```